# What's is this kinda decryption?

Tags: encryption, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I have here a code that come from dissamble decompiler Ghidra.
It's use for decoding some encrypted binary file into the html(plain-text).
I want to know how the function work and what's the decode algorithm it use(If it not an custom decode).

Im pretty sure this is decode function because when the debugger run through this function it show the decoded html in the memory dump.
(I have named some variable, im not expert maybe some variable are wrong)

so, how's this decoder work?
I go for some research and found that it's might be something about chiper?

```
void CRYPT_decrypt_content(uint *rawdata,uint *decrypted,uint *param_3)

{
  byte rawData_B3_RShift8;
  ulonglong PROCED_single_rawData_B2;
  ulonglong PROCED_single_rawData_B3;
  ulonglong PROCED_single_rawData_B1;
  ulonglong PROCED_single_rawData_B0;
  uint *shifted8_R8_reg;
  int i;
  byte rawData_B3_RShift16;
  uint PROCED_multi_1;
  uint PROCED_multi_2;
  uint PROCED_multi_3;
  uint rawData_B0;
  uint rawData_B1;
  uint rawData_B2;
  uint rawData_B3;
  
                    /* Sub Rawdata into Diff Var
                       Use key or some data in R8 Register to calculate decryption */
  rawData_B3 = rawdata[3];
  rawData_B2 = rawdata[2];
  rawData_B1 = rawdata[1];
  rawData_B0 = *rawdata;
  PROCED_single_rawData_B3 =
       ((ulonglong)(rawData_B3 >> 8 | rawData_B3 << 24) & 0xff00ff00 |
       (ulonglong)((rawData_B3 & 0xff00) << 8 | rawData_B3 >> 24)) ^ (ulonglong)param_3[3];
  PROCED_single_rawData_B2 =
       ((ulonglong)(rawData_B2 >> 8 | rawData_B2 << 24) & 0xff00ff00 |
       (ulonglong)((rawData_B2 & 0xff00) << 8 | rawData_B2 >> 24)) ^ (ulonglong)param_3[2];
  PROCED_single_rawData_B1 =
       ((ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 8 | rawData_B1 << 24) & 0xff00ff00 |
       (ulonglong)((rawData_B1 & 0xff00) << 8 | rawData_B1 >> 24)) ^ (ulonglong)param_3[1];
  PROCED_single_rawData_B0 =
       ((ulonglong)(rawData_B0 >> 8 | rawData_B0 << 24) & 0xff00ff00 |
       (ulonglong)((rawData_B0 & 0xff00) << 8 | rawData_B0 >> 0x18)) ^ (ulonglong)*param_3;
                    /* Re set RawData block to new Processed data + some algorithm */
  rawData_B3 = *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B3 >> 16 & 255) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B2 >> 8 & 0xff) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B0 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B1 & 0xff) * 4) ^ param_3[4];
  rawData_B0 = *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B3 >> 8 & 0xff) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B0 >> 0x10 & 0xff) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B1 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B2 & 0xff) * 4) ^ param_3[5];
  shifted8_R8_reg = param_3 + 8;
  rawData_B2 = *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B0 >> 8 & 0xff) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B1 >> 0x10 & 0xff) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B2 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B3 & 0xff) * 4) ^ param_3[6];
  i = (int)param_3[60] >> 1;
  rawData_B1 = *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B1 >> 8 & 0xff) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B2 >> 0x10 & 0xff) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B3 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
               *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + (PROCED_single_rawData_B0 & 0xff) * 4) ^ param_3[7];
  while( true ) {
    i = i + -1;
    rawData_B3_RShift8 = (byte)(rawData_B3 >> 8);
    rawData_B3_RShift16 = (byte)(rawData_B3 >> 16);
                    /* Infinitly execute until BREAK kw */
    if (i == 0) break;
    PROCED_multi_1 =
         *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B0 >> 8) & 0xff) * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B2 >> 0x10) & 0xff) * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + (ulonglong)(rawData_B3 & 0xff) * 4) ^ shifted8_R8_reg[3];
    PROCED_multi_2 =
         *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + (ulonglong)rawData_B3_RShift8 * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B0 >> 0x10) & 0xff) * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(rawData_B2 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + ((ulonglong)rawData_B1 & 0xff) * 4) ^ shifted8_R8_reg[2];
    PROCED_multi_3 =
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + (ulonglong)rawData_B3_RShift16 * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 8) & 0xff) * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(rawData_B0 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
         *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + ((ulonglong)rawData_B2 & 0xff) * 4) ^ shifted8_R8_reg[1];
    rawData_B1 = *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B2 >> 8) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 0x10) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(rawData_B3 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + ((ulonglong)rawData_B0 & 0xff) * 4) ^ *shifted8_R8_reg ;
                    /* rawData_b1 Act as PROCED_multi_4 */
    rawData_B3 = *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + ((ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_2 >> 8) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + ((ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_1 >> 0x10) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + ((ulonglong)PROCED_multi_3 & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 shifted8_R8_reg[4];
    rawData_B0 = *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 0x10) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + ((ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_1 >> 8) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_3 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + ((ulonglong)PROCED_multi_2 & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 shifted8_R8_reg[5];
    rawData_B2 = *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + ((ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 8) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + ((ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_3 >> 0x10) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_2 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + ((ulonglong)PROCED_multi_1 & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 shifted8_R8_reg[6];
    rawData_B1 = *(uint *)(&DAT_1800086a0 + ((ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_3 >> 8) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008aa0 + ((ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_2 >> 0x10) & 0xff) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180008fa0 + (ulonglong)(PROCED_multi_1 >> 0x18) * 4) ^
                 *(uint *)(&DAT_180009fd0 + ((ulonglong)rawData_B1 & 0xff) * 4) ^ shifted8_R8_reg[ 7]
    ;
                    /* Shift PTR by 8 */
    shifted8_R8_reg = shifted8_R8_reg + 8;
  }
                    /* while true jne Here Above */
  PROCED_multi_1 =
       CONCAT31(CONCAT21(CONCAT11((&DAT_180008ea0)[rawData_B3 >> 0x18],
                                  (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 0x10) & 0xff]),
                         (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)(rawData_B2 >> 8) & 0xff]),
                (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)rawData_B0 & 0xff]) ^ *shifted8_R8_reg;
  *decrypted = PROCED_multi_1 >> 8 & 0xff00ff00 | PROCED_multi_1 << 0x18 |
               (PROCED_multi_1 & 0xff00) << 8 | PROCED_multi_1 >> 0x18;
  PROCED_multi_1 =
       CONCAT31(CONCAT21(CONCAT11((&DAT_180008ea0)[rawData_B0 >> 0x18],
                                  (&DAT_180008ea0)[rawData_B3_RShift16]),
                         (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)(rawData_B1 >> 8) & 0xff]),
                (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)rawData_B2 & 0xff]) ^ shifted8_R8_reg[1];
  decrypted[1] = PROCED_multi_1 >> 8 & 0xff00ff00 | PROCED_multi_1 << 0x18 |
                 (PROCED_multi_1 & 0xff00) << 8 | PROCED_multi_1 >> 0x18;
  PROCED_multi_1 =
       CONCAT31(CONCAT21(CONCAT11((&DAT_180008ea0)[rawData_B2 >> 0x18],
                                  (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)(rawData_B0 >> 0x10) & 0xff]),
                         (&DAT_180008ea0)[rawData_B3_RShift8]),
                (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)rawData_B1 & 0xff]) ^ shifted8_R8_reg[2];
  decrypted[2] = PROCED_multi_1 >> 8 & 0xff00ff00 | PROCED_multi_1 << 0x18 |
                 (PROCED_multi_1 & 0xff00) << 8 | PROCED_multi_1 >> 0x18;
  rawData_B3 = CONCAT31(CONCAT21(CONCAT11((&DAT_180008ea0)[rawData_B1 >> 0x18],
                                          (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)(rawData_B2 >> 0x10) & 0xff] ),
                                 (&DAT_180008ea0)[(ulonglong)(rawData_B0 >> 8) & 0xff]),
                        (&DAT_180008ea0)[rawData_B3 & 0xff]) ^ shifted8_R8_reg[3];
  decrypted[3] = rawData_B3 >> 8 & 0xff00ff00 | rawData_B3 << 0x18 |
                 (rawData_B3 & 0xff00) << 8 | rawData_B3 >> 0x18;
  return;
}
```

And here is the caller of this function

```
decrypted_memaddrPTR = (uint *)operator_new((longlong)(filesize + 16));
  CRYPT_decrypt_content(EncryptedRawData,decrypted_memaddrPTR,Decryption_key);
  if (0x10 < filesize) {
    lVar5 = (longlong)decrypted_memaddrPTR - (longlong)EncryptedRawData;
    i._0_4_ = (filesize - 17U >> 4) + 1;
    i = (ulonglong)(uint)i;
    do {
                    /* shift pointer to new block of data */
      EncryptedRawData = EncryptedRawData + 4;
      CRYPT_decrypt_content
                (EncryptedRawData,(uint *)(lVar5 + (longlong)EncryptedRawData),Decryption_key);
      i = i - 1;
    } while (i != 0);
}
```

So far I understand as following,
The EncryptedRawData is the PTR to the memory address of the rawdata.
decrypted_memaddrPTR is where(memory address) the decoded data store.
Decryption_key (i think)is pointer to where the key is in memory.

If you guys need more info, I will reply if i able to find it

Note: The caller is in another function that exported from this dll and use as external function in dotnet of another application!